# Im trying to put numbers in to the array without putting their duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

My code returns 0 for the length. It should return 5 after excluding the duplicates from the array. I think im missing something in my code that just isnt coming to mind. Can someone quickly review it and tell me what is missing? I would prefer that my code is used in the solution and not a brand new one. Thank you

Question:
Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates
in-place such that each element appear only once and return the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this
by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

```js
const numbers = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

const removeDuplicates = (nums) => {
    nums.sort()
    const newArr = []

    //or just count how many numbers there are excluding their duplicates
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
            if(!nums[i] === nums[j]){
                 newArr.push(nums[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(newArr)
    return newArr.length
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new array: `remove the duplicates in-place`

Comment: You're given a sorted array already, calling `.sort()` on it will not only result in an unnecessary increase in computational complexity, it also won't sort properly. The problem statement also explicitly says not to create a new array, but that's what you're doing.

Comment: I did sort in case the array passed into the function isnt sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is this line:

```
            if(!nums[i] === nums[j]){
```

You probably intend to do:

```
            if(nums[i] !== nums[j]){
```

That said, there is something wrong with your logic in having the nested for loops. This is probably what you intended:

```js
const numbers = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

const removeDuplicates = (nums) => {
    nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const newArr = [];

    let prev = -Infinity;
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] === prev)
            continue;
        newArr.push(nums[i]);
        prev = nums[i];
    }

    console.log(newArr);
    return newArr.length;
};

removeDuplicates(numbers);
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the correction. Can you explain the -Infinity & continue part?

Comment: `prev = -Infinity;` only initializes the variable to something that your input array does not contain.

Comment: if current number is not same as the `previous` number we continue to the next value. Else we add it to the `newArr`.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks! Can you send a link that explains what -infinity is further?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY

Answer (score 0):

To do it in place you must use array.splice(). Something like this:

```
let i = numbers.length - 1
do {
  let x = numbers.indexOf(numbers[i])
  if ( x !== i ) {
    numbers.splice(x,1)
  }
  i -= 1
} while ( i > 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve this.

```
    const numbers = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
      if(accumulator.indexOf(currentValue) === -1){
        return [...accumulator, currentValue]
      }
      return accumulator
    }
    
    const removeDuplicates = arr => arr.reduce(reducer, []);
    
    removeDuplicates(numbers) // -> output [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```